# Is there a fiddler proxy equivalent for Debian?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, proxy

I like to setup a (SOCKS) proxy on my Debian system. For certain URLS/domains I like it to execute my code (C, C#, JS, I don't care really) with the url and server response (html or JSON). The domain uses https so I'll need to install a certificate. But I don't know what tools are needed and there seems to be many proxies for Linux.

Comment: Why not just use Fiddler?

Comment: @cutrightjm because I want the proxy on my pi and my pi doesn't run windows/fiddler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddler can be run through mono on linux

more info: http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono